# Python server not responding (CORS policy?)

Tags: javascript, python, server

I have an issue. I code a little something mixing Javascript and Python. The idea is that I drag and drop files into a canvas and an Ajax request is sent to a python server that is running locally in a thread.

Basically, the Javascript part looks like this:

```js
$(document).on('drop', '#canvas', function(e) {
  if(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer) {

    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files,
        formData = new FormData(),
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // main function here

    xhr.open("POST", 'http://localhost:8001/upload_images.py', true)
    xhr.send(formData)
```

The backend is just a python `SimpleHttpServer`:

```py
class FileUploadHTTPRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1"

    def end_headers(self):
        # overwrite SimpleHTTPRequestHandler to handle CORS policy
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')
        BaseHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self)

    def do_POST(self):
        """Handle a POST request."""

        # main code here

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "Application/json")
        self.send_header("Content-Length", len(response_str))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(response_str.encode('utf-8'))

    def do_OPTIONS(self):
        # handle Pre-flight
        self.send_response(200, "ok")

        # call our own end_headers to handle pre-flight
        self.end_headers()
```

The thing is. When I run this code on **Windows 10** with google chrome, everything works. I can see that my **POST** request sent from my Javascript is received first as an **OPTIONS** in my python server (pre-flight) and then the real **POST** requests is executed and everything works and my image is displayed into my canvas

On the other hand, now that I've put my working piece of code on **Ubuntu** with either Chromium/Chrome... The code doesn't work anymore. The **POST** from my Javascript is sent. It is still received as an **OPTIONS** in my python server but then it never entered into my **do_POST** from my python server.

In the chrome debugger under Ubuntu, under network, I can see "Caution: request is not finished yet". So it looks like the **do_OPTIONS** response was never received by the Javascript in the first place and my request is still hanging in the void...

I'm lost. I don't understand why It works on Windows+google chrome but not on Ubuntu+chrome...

Note:
I've tried changing the ports, the changing "end_headers()" and lot's of other things but I can make it work...

I hope someone already encountered this issue.

**Edit**: While debugging on both machines. I noticed that, on Ubuntu, the code crashes in `handle_one_request(self)` from server.py of the `http`  library.

The line: `self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65337)` is the faulty one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally make it worked!

As you can see in my original post, my class starts with:

```py
class FileUploadHTTPRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1"
    ...
```

Well, actually, if you remove the `protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1` class property, then it is working. I'm not sure why it was working just fine on WIndows + Chrome but not on Ubuntu + Chrome

**Note**: the version of Chrome are similar on both OS

I searched a bit on the internet but I didn't find explanations as why preicising the HTTP protocol version impact so much the code... If somebody knows how precising or not the HTTP protocol version affect the code I would be glad to know